# LXC CentOS Container does not work with multiple IP addresses

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, lxc, proxmox, ovh

Hoping someone can help me as i've been pulling out the only hair I have left (which is not much) trying to figure this out.

I'm unable to assign multiple IPs to any CentOS 7 container, only the first adapter/IP works correctly. This only happens on RHEL (CentOS 7 specifically) containers. I do not have this issue with any Debian containers, which is what puzzles me so much about this.

Server is on OVH network, configured all IPs with virtual MAC in OVH manager interface.

All debian based containers work fine with multiple IPs and network adapters, but for some reason any CentOS 7 containers will only work with the first IP added to the container. I tried using different failover IPs from other subnets, all without luck.

I'm able to ping the main IP of the CentOS container from host node, but not able to ping any additional ones added from the host.

Here's the `/etc/network/interfaces` file from host node:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth2 inet manual

# for Routing
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        post-up /etc/pve/kvm-networking.sh
        bridge_ports dummy0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0


# vmbr0: Bridging. Make sure to use only MAC adresses that were assigned to you.
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 149.x.x.155
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 149.x.x.0
        broadcast 149.x.x.255
        gateway 149.x.x.254
        bridge_ports eth2
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address 2607:5300:0061:039b::
        netmask 64
        post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add 2607:5300:0061:03ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev vmbr0
        post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add default via 2607:5300:0061:03ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del default via 2607:5300:0061:03ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del 2607:5300:0061:03ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev vmbr0
```

Here's the results of `ip link` in the guest (CentOS 7) container:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
84: eth0@if85: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:xx:xx:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
86: eth1@if87: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:xx:xx:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

Here's the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=167.xxx.xxx.214
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=149.xxx.xxx.254
```

Here's the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` file:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=167.xxx.xxx.215
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=149.xxx.xxx.254
```

Is there something i'm missing here guys? I'm completely stumped by this one as it only appears to be an issue on RHEL (CentOS specifically) ... any suggestions, comments, or ideas to help troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Running Proxmox:

```
proxmox-ve: 4.4-84 (running kernel: 4.4.44-1-pve)
pve-manager: 4.4-12 (running version: 4.4-12/e71b7a74)
pve-kernel-4.4.35-2-pve: 4.4.35-79
pve-kernel-4.4.44-1-pve: 4.4.44-84
pve-kernel-4.4.19-1-pve: 4.4.19-66
lvm2: 2.02.116-pve3
corosync-pve: 2.4.2-2~pve4+1
libqb0: 1.0-1
pve-cluster: 4.0-48
qemu-server: 4.0-109
pve-firmware: 1.1-10
libpve-common-perl: 4.0-92
libpve-access-control: 4.0-23
libpve-storage-perl: 4.0-76
pve-libspice-server1: 0.12.8-2
vncterm: 1.3-1
pve-docs: 4.4-3
pve-qemu-kvm: 2.7.1-4
pve-container: 1.0-96
pve-firewall: 2.0-33
pve-ha-manager: 1.0-40
ksm-control-daemon: 1.2-1
glusterfs-client: 3.5.2-2+deb8u3
lxc-pve: 2.0.7-4
lxcfs: 2.0.6-pve1
criu: 1.6.0-1
novnc-pve: 0.5-8
smartmontools: 6.5+svn4324-1~pve80
zfsutils: 0.6.5.9-pve15~bpo80
```

Comment: Why do you have two virtual NICs in the container? This is completely unnecessary. Just assign both IPs on one of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton just following the guide for Proxmox when using OVH http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/OVH

Comment: @MichaelHampton so adding a custom `eth0:0` did work, but I also have to manually add the route on the host `ip route add x.x.x.x dev vmbr0` for it to work correctly ... so still stuck between a rock and hard place :(

Answer (score 0):

Having this issue again almost 6 years later, found my own question, and here's how I solved it:

Use normal bridge config (don't need to use routing)

For CentOS or AlmaLinux in OVH you need to set each failover IP with the **same MAC address** and then just add like normal.

Profit!